# First-child styling only works on first element

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I got some code where I'm selecting some elements by first child, and then styling the accordingly. I noticed that it behaves quite strangely, and the css is only being applied to the first element. I tried to select them both with JS, and it seems like, although I'm doing the exact same thing, just on another element, it doesn't return the div.

Code:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".index-0:first-child")); // returns div
console.log(document.querySelector(".index-1:first-child")); // returns null
```

```css
.index-0:first-child {
  color: green;
}

.index-1:first-child {
  color: blue;
  /* doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<div class="index-0">
  <p class="message"></p>
  <div class="shout">
    <span>Message 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="index-1">
  <p class="message"></p>
  <div class="shout">
    <span>Message 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4k03eny/1/

Comment: Only the element with the class `.index-0` is the first child of its parent element. `.index-1` is not the first child of its parent.

Comment: What is it within those `.index-N` elements that you want to style? Or do you want to style the whole thing? If so, why the `:first-child`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how CSS selectors work. (You're not alone; this is a very frequent misunderstanding.) Compound selectors like `.index-1:first-child` or `div.foo` are "AND" operations for their individual parts: `.index-1:first-child` means that it matches an element that's got the class `index-1` **and** is the first child of its parent. Your `.index-1` element *isn't* the first child in its parent, it's the second child.

In this case, you'd use `.index-1` to style it, without the `:first-child` bit.

(If your goal is to style the first child *within* `.index-1`, add a `>` (a [child combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)):

```
.index-1 > :first-child {
    color: green;
}
```

...but I don't think that's what you're trying to do. Or you could use a space [a [descendant combinator]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators), but that would apply to **all** elements within `.index-1` that were the first child of their parent, which I also suspect isn't what you want to do.)

---

From you comment:

> I want to style the first element that has a new class differently.

You can do that by combining `.index-1:first-child` with `:not(.index-1) + .index-1`:

```
.index-1:first-child, :not(.index-1) + .index-1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

That latter uses an *adjacent sibling combinator* to say "apply the rules to an `.index-1` that isn't immediately after an `.index-1`):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".index-0:first-child, :not(.index-0) + .index-0"));
console.log(document.querySelector(".index-1:first-child, :not(.index-1) + .index-1"));
```

```css
.index-0:first-child, :not(.index-0) + .index-0 {
    color: green;
}

.index-1:first-child, :not(.index-1) + .index-1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-0">
  <p class="message"></p>
  <div class="shout">
    <span>Message 1</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="index-1">
  <p class="message"></p>
  <div class="shout">
    <span>Message 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, that requires that you style them specifically (rules for `.index-0`, `.index-1`, etc.). You can't do it **generically** in CSS, but you could in JavaScript. This looks through all elements with the class `index`, picks out their `index-N` class name if they have it, and adds `highlight` to the first in any given run of them:

```
var lastClass = null;
document.querySelectorAll(".index").forEach(function(e) {
  var m = e.className.match(/(?:^| )(index-\d+)(?: |$)/);
  var thisClass = m ? m[1] : null;
  if (thisClass != lastClass) {
    lastClass = thisClass;
    e.classList.add("highlight");
  }
});
```

Example:

```js
var lastClass = null;
document.querySelectorAll(".index").forEach(function(e) {
  var m = e.className.match(/(?:^| )(index-\d+)(?: |$)/);
  var thisClass = m ? m[1] : null;
  if (thisClass != lastClass) {
    lastClass = thisClass;
    e.classList.add("highlight");
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="index index-0">
  <p class="message"></p>
  <div class="shout">
    <span>first .index-0</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="index index-0">
  <p class="message"></p>
  <div class="shout">
    <span>second .index-0 in a row</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="index index-1">
  <p class="message"></p>
  <div class="shout">
    <span>first .index-1</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Many browsers now support `forEach` on the NodeList returned by `querySelectorAll`, but not quite all do. You can polyfill it if missing:

```
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" &&
    NodeList.prototype &&
    !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "forEach", {
        value: Array.prototype.forEach
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the exaplanation. My problem is that I have several divs at the same level, that may or may not have the same class. I want to style the first element that has a new class differently. https://jsfiddle.net/a4k03eny/3/

Comment: @StephanOlsen: You can do that with an *adjacent sibling combinator* (in a group with your original `:first-child` selector). I've added to the end of the answer.